# C++ Errors trying to overload the / operator in a templated class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, template-classes

I'm trying to overload the '+', '-', and '/' operators for a templated class i created.
the + and - operators work perfectly, but the / operator overload is giving me errors.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013

```
//Set.h 
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Set
{   
    friend Set<T> operator+ <> (const Set& left, const Set& right);  //works
    friend Set<T> operator- <> (const Set& left, const Set& right);  //works
    friend Set<T> operator/ <> (const Set& left, const Set& right);  //does not

public:
    Set(int n)
    {
        numItems = n;
        setItems();
    }
    Set()
    {
        numItems = 0;
        setItems();
    }
    ~Set();
    void setItems();
    void output();
private:
    int numItems;
    vector<T> set;
};
```

I am wanting to overload the / operator to determine the [intersection of two sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Intersections)

Definition:

```
    //---------------- Overload intersection -----------------
template<class T>
Set<T> operator/(const Set<T>& left, const Set<T>& right)
{
    bool putin = false;
    Set<T> quotient;

    // loops through left Set
    for (int i = 0; i < left.set.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < right.set.size(); j++)
            //loops through right set
        {
            //checks if the item in left is in right set
            // if it is, PUT IT IN the new set
            if (left.set[i] == right.set[j])
                putin = true;
        }
        if (putin)
            quotient.set.push_back(left.set[i]);
        putin = true;
    }

    return quotient;
}
```

Here are the errors i'm getting

`Error  1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'`

`Error  2   error C2460: '/' : uses 'Set<T>', which is being defined`

`Error  3   error C2433: '/' : 'friend' not permitted on data declarations`

`Error  4   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'`

`Error  5   error C2365: '/' : redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable'`

`Error  6   error C2904: '/' : name already used for a template in the current scope`

`Error  7   error C2460: '/' : uses 'Set<int>', which is being defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky, and it is covered by a [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/template-friends.html) entry.

I can't explain exactly why your compiler gives the errors it does. But your code for all the operators is incorrect:  as explained in the FAQ, the compiler thinks you are trying to `friend` a non-template function, however this cannot work because the functions do need to be template functions in order to accept a `Set<T>`.

The FAQ's suggested solution is to declare the template functions first , before you friend them:

```
template<typename T> class Set;

template<typename T>
Set<T> operator+ (const Set<T>& left, const Set<T>& right);
template<typename T>
Set<T> operator- (const Set<T>& left, const Set<T>& right); 
template<typename T>
Set<T> operator/ (const Set<T>& left, const Set<T>& right); 

template<class T>
class Set
{   
    friend Set<T> operator+ <> (const Set<T>& left, const Set<T>& right);
    friend Set<T> operator- <> (const Set<T>& left, const Set<T>& right);
    friend Set<T> operator/ <> (const Set<T>& left, const Set<T>& right);
```

Note that you need to be using `Set<T>`, not just `Set` as in your original code.
This works because now the compiler knows we are talking about function templates, so it recognizes them in the `friend` line.

Another possible solution is this, without the forward-declarations of functions:

```
template<class T>
class Set
{   
template<class U>
friend Set<U> operator / (const Set<U>& left, const Set<U>& right); 
template<class U>
friend Set<U> operator+ (const Set<U>& left, const Set<U>& right);
template<class U>
friend Set<U> operator- (const Set<U>& left, const Set<U>& right);
public:
// ...
```

where you explicitly refer to template functions as friends. I'm not completely sure that this second approach is a good idea.

If your operators have "normal" semantics then perhaps you can avoid this issue together, but not using `friend`s at all. If you define member functions `operator+=`, `operator-=`, `operator/=` that operate on `*this`, then it is simple to declare the other operators, outside of the class, that delegate to those functions without needing to be friends:

```
template<typename T> 
Set<T> operator+ (Set<T> a, Set<T> const &b} { return a += b; }
```